# listen to dial during conference call

Tags: ruby, twilio

I have two users in a conference call. I bring in a 3rd user by using twilio api to dial their number and add to the same conference.

The problem though is that the 1st and 2nd users don't hear anything while 3rd user is dialed so they have no idea what is going on.

**Is there a way for the people in the conference room to hear the ringing when a 3rd person is being called?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there is no way play the audio from the dial to a 3rd user into a conference call using Twilio.

Comment: Seems like my issue would be a common one. Any suggestions on how to make this user experience better?

Comment: It depends really. In your call is one of the users an admin and making the call to the third party? Are they connected to the call using [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript) or are they on their phone?

Comment: Twilio client and some twilio api calls.

Comment: In that case I recommend you try using the [status callback parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#statuscallback-parameter) to get events from the call and push them into the interface for the Twilio Client user.

Comment: So basically push the events to the call? To announce things like "initiated, ringing, answered"? That sounds like a great idea actually.

Comment: Well, I meant to push that to the screen of your call admin, so that they can know what's going on in the call. To announce those things would take a bot user dialling into the conference in order to `<Say>` things.